# Print stacktrace directly in errorpage?

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I'd like to print the stacktrace directly within the error page (at least a few lines).

In JSP it would be something like this:

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
<% exception.printStackTrace(); %>
```

How can I do similar with JSF2 in my Facelets page? Any chance without a backing bean?

Comment: What's wrong with backing beans? The design principle behind JSF is to avoid writing java code in presentation layer (i.e. jsp/facelets templates) but keep Java code in Java files. Why do you need so much to put Java code printing exception directly in JSF page tempalte?